# SharePoint App Upgrade Failure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

We are developing an Angular based SharePoint hosted application that installs successfully through F5 deployment from visual studio and also through our CI process (via PowerShell). However, when trying to upgrade the app package, there is an undefined runtime exception thrown. Looking through the ULS logs the failure seems to be caused by the following issue:

> Safe mode did not start successfully.
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: This page
>   has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if
>   this problem persists.
>
> Could not find Web Part [Unknown:
>   a6524906-3fd2-ee4e-23ee-252d3c6e0dc9] on page
>   /site/_catalogs/design/AllItems.aspx in the safe controls list.

This is repeated several times and seems bizarre given that we have no custom web parts in the host web (and they obviously can't be deployed in the app web).

Has anyone seen or managed to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: can you see that entry into web.config file?\

Comment: good shout, gave me a bit of a brain wave. The deployment and upgrade of the application was being triggered on a dedicated 'admin' server in the farm but NOT a WFE running the IIS websites where the web.config file was located. Short answer is that the Upgrade-SPAppInstance command must be run on a WFE as it seems to have a dependency on aspx components like web parts which the original install command does not.